# Scrapyd: No active project - How to schedule spiders with scrapyd

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to schedule a scrapy 2.1.0 spider with the help of scrapyd 1.2

```
 curl --insecure http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=bid -d spider=test
```

This should in theory start the crawl for spider test within project bid. Instead it outputs the error message:

```
 {"node_name": "spider1", "status": "error", "message": "Scrapy 2.1.0 - no active project\n\nUnknown command: list\n\nUse \"scrapy\" to see available commands\n"}
```

If I cd into the project directory there is the project with several spiders which I can start via "cd /var/spiders/ && scrapy crawl test &".

However beeing in another folder would also give me the message "no active projects":

```
/var$ scrapy list
Scrapy 2.1.0 - no active project

Unknown command: list

Use "scrapy" to see available commands
```

This looks like the exact same info I get from scrapyd, so I suspect that I need to configure somehow the working directory where my projects live.

Scrapyd is running and I can access the console via web "gui".

What is the right approach to start the job via scrapyd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can launch your spider with scrapyd, you'll have to deploy your spider first. You can do this by:

- Using addversion.json (https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#addversion-json)
- Using scrapyd-deploy (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client)

Comment: OK, thank you. I am now a step closer. Unfortunatelly stuck with another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620407/scrapyd-deploy-errors-due-to-using-os-path-to-set-directory