# Scrapyd-Deploy: SPIDER_MODULES not found

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd, scrapyd-deploy

I am trying to deploy a scrapy 2.1.0 project with scrapy-deploy 1.2 and get this error:

```
scrapyd-deploy example
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/scrapyd-deploy:23: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.utils.http` is deprecated, Please import from `w3lib.http` instead.
  from scrapy.utils.http import basic_auth_header
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
Packing version r1-master
Deploying to project "crawler" in http://myip:6843/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"node_name": "spider1", "status": "error", "message": "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py:90: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Use of environment variables prefixed with SCRAPY_ to override settings is deprecated. The following environment variables are currently defined: EGG_VERSION\n  warnings.warn(\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 193, in _run_module_as_main\n    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 86, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 40, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 37, in main\n    execute()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py\", line 142, in execute\n    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py\", line 280, in __init__\n    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py\", line 152, in __init__\n    self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py\", line 146, in _get_spider_loader\n    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py\", line 60, in from_settings\n    return cls(settings)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py\", line 24, in __init__\n    self._load_all_spiders()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py\", line 46, in _load_all_spiders\n    for module in walk_modules(name):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py\", line 69, in walk_modules\n    mod = import_module(path)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1014, in _gcd_import\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 991, in _find_and_load\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crawler.spiders_prod'\n"}
```

crawler.spiders_prod is the first module defined in SPIDER_MODULES

Part of crawler.settings.py:

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawler.spiders_prod', 'crawler.spiders_dev']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawler.spiders_dev'
```

The crawler works localy, but using deploy it will fail to use whatever I call the folder where my spiders live in.

scrapyd-deploy setup.py:

```
# Automatically created by: scrapyd-deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = crawler.settings']},
)
```

scrapy.cfg:

```
[deploy:example]
url = http://myip:6843/
username = test
password = whatever.
project = crawler
version = GIT
```

Is this possibly a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules have to be initialised within scrapy. This happens through simply placing the following file into each folder defined as a module:

```
__init__.py
```

This has solved my described problem.

Learning:

If you want to split your spiders into folders, it is not enough to simple create a folder and specify this folder as a module within the settings file, but you also need to place this file into the new folder. Funny engough the crawler works, without the file just deployment to scrapyd fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking at complex solutions while it was this.
Sometimes things are just simple :)